# setCookie: как проверяется истекло ли время жизни cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, при установке функцией `setCookie` времени жизни `cookie`, например

```
setСookie( $inKey , '345' , time()+3600  );
```

как проверяется то, что время жизни еще не истекло? Используется время на клиентской машине или на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` выдет метку времени с начала эпохи Unix, т.е.(The Unix Epoch, 1 января 1970, 00:00:00 GMT) до текущего времени. и оно никоим образом не привязано к веремени сервера или пользователя.

Comment: нет, я спрашивала не про функцию тайм, а про то, как происходит проверка того, устарели ли куки

Comment: ну как, сервером.... он контролирует на своей стороне. если кука у клиента, то браузер контролирует время щизни куки... при этом не важно какая временная зона у пользователя и у сервера.

Comment: т.е. не важно, в каком часовом поясе находится сервер и клиент, если указать, что кука должна жить полчаса, то у всех пользователей она проживет полчаса?

Comment: да, именно поэтому в всех временных данных лучше использовать time(), т.е. unix time stamp.

Comment: Если у пользователя часы на полчаса отстают - то куку на полчаса ему не поставить. А временная зона не важна, т.к. она отправляется в параметре `expires`.

Comment: да, с неправильно выставленным временем будут разные неприятности...

Comment: Теперь меня мучает вопрос - зачем ставить куку на полчаса? Хоть один пример использования... )

Answer (score 2):

`if(isset($_COOKIE['some_cookie'])) { /* ... */ }`

`if(!isset($_COOKIE['some_cookie'])) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: ммм, видимо такой ответ дожидалась девушка, чтото я не в ту сторону подумал)))

Comment: спасибо, но я совсем не про то )

Answer (score 1):

Браузер просто удаляет куку у которой истекло время жизни(во время обращения по url) и не присылает её серверу, соответственно сервер не видит куку и все счастливы.

Короче ответ - **никак не проверяется** - либо кука есть либо ее нет. клиент даже не присылает серверу никакие данные по куке, кроме ее имени и значения.

Тем не менее данные о жизни куки можно получить на стороне клиента в js.